# Hi frnds, i am working in Android 2.1.when moving from one Activity to another Activity,it didnot show the GUI of the next Activity 

Tags: android, android-manifest

//----AppActivity.java

public class AppActivity extends Activity {

```
Button Login;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.signup);

    Login=(Button)findViewById(R.id.login);
    Login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent=new Intent(v.getContext(),Login.class);
            //intent.setClass(AppActivity.this,Login.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}
```

}

//---Login.java

public class Login extends Activity{

```
public void onCreat(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
    setContentView(R.layout.login);

}
```

}

//-----signup.xml

```
    <Button android:layout_height="40dip"    
    android:id="@+id/login" 
    android:text="@string/login" 
    android:layout_width="90dip"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true">

    </Button>

   </RelativeLayout>
```

//----login.xml

```
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/uname" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/uname">
    </TextView>

    <EditText android:text="" 
    android:layout_width="200dip" 
    android:id="@+id/unameText" 
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/uname" 
    android:layout_height="35dip">
    </EditText>

    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/pword" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="PassWord "
    android:layout_below="@+id/unameText">
    </TextView>

    <EditText android:text="" 
    android:layout_width="200dip" 
    android:id="@+id/pwordText" 
    android:layout_below="@+id/unameText"
    android:layout_height="35dip"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/pword" 
    android:password="true">     
    </EditText>       

    <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
     android:id="@+id/submit" 
     android:text="Submit" 
     android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
     android:layout_below="@+id/unameText">         
     </Button>
</RelativeLayout>
```

//----Manifest.xml

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".AppActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">   
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>              
    </activity>

     <activity android:name=".Login"
               android:label="Login Page" >                   
     </activity>


</application>
```

---Plz see my code and help me to find where i m doing mistake or any other way to solve my problem. Thanks in advance :)
                                In Brief==>  In AppActivity.java,when i Click LoginButton, its move to Login.java but not showing GUI UserName,Password and Submit Button fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i can see In your Login.java

```
public void onCreat(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
    setContentView(R.layout.login);

}
```

onCreate() method is misspelled, check that first

Comment: Thanks Zoombie.Its now Working Properly.:)

Comment: @ArUmOy: just for info, onCreate() is override callback method in lifecycle of Activity, if defined as onCreat() it becomes a normal method, which is not called by Activity lifecycle, thats why you might have face such situation, but it happens..